# Rust: "returning this value requires that `'op` must outlive `'static`" with HRTB in closure returning future

Tags: rust

Consider the following minimal example:

```rust
type Task<'a> = Box<dyn std::future::Future<Output = ()> + 'a>;

type Context<'s> = &'s str;

trait MyTrait {
    fn compute<'a>(&'a self, ctx: Context<'a>) -> Task<'a>
    where
        Self: 'a;
}

impl<F: for<'b> Fn(Context<'b>) -> Task<'b>> MyTrait for F {
    fn compute<'a>(&'a self, ctx: Context<'a>) -> Task<'a>
    where
        Self: 'a,
    {
        (self)(ctx)
    }
}

fn bla<'op>(input: &'op usize) -> impl MyTrait + 'op {
    let v: Box<dyn for<'b> Fn(Context<'b>) -> Task<'b> + 'op> = Box::new(move |ctx| {
        Box::new(async move {
            println!("{}", &ctx[*input..]);
            ()
        })
    });
    v
}
```

The compiler generated error message is:

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:22:9
   |
20 |   fn bla<'op>(input: &'op usize) -> impl MyTrait + 'op {
   |          --- lifetime `'op` defined here
21 |       let v: Box<dyn for<'b> Fn(Context<'b>) -> Task<'b> + 'op> = Box::new(move |ctx| {
22 | /         Box::new(async move {
23 | |             println!("{}", &ctx[*input..]);
24 | |             ()
25 | |         })
   | |__________^ returning this value requires that `'op` must outlive `'static`
```

I don't understand why `'op` must outlive `'static`. The lifetime of the returned `Task` is bound by `'b` which in turn is shorter than the `Self` of the boxed closure, and thus of `'op`.

I also tried to model the lifetime of the trait object more explicitly, but got the same error message from this:

```rust
type Task<'a> = Box<dyn std::future::Future<Output = ()> + 'a>;

type Context<'s> = &'s str;

trait MyTrait<'l> {
    fn compute<'a>(&'l self, ctx: Context<'a>) -> Task<'l>
    where
        'l: 'a;
}

impl<'c, F: 'c + for<'b> Fn(Context<'b>) -> Task<'b>> MyTrait<'c> for F {
    fn compute<'a>(&'c self, ctx: Context<'a>) -> Task<'c>
    where
        'c: 'a,
    {
        (self)(ctx)
    }
}

fn bla<'op>(input: &'op usize) -> impl MyTrait<'op> + 'op {
    let v: Box<dyn for<'b> Fn(Context<'b>) -> Task<'b> + 'op> = Box::new(move |ctx| {
        Box::new(async move {
            println!("{}", &ctx[*input..]);
            ()
        })
    });
    v
}
```

Edit: I guess another more open way of asking this question would be: How to I constrain the lifetime of a HRTB by an outer lifetime?

Comment: I gave an explanation "why" below. For solving it... well, you can, but as far as I know, only if you can change the signatures of pretty much everything involved (and the solution is pretty hacky). What can you change.

Comment: Example of how it works: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=727142ab0165725c99041c8978037f42.

Comment: [Here's another way, with less changes but more restrictive implementation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f1aab755d47930a6de2fbc2e4861dd95).

Comment: For my use case changing the signature was not a problem, so your workaround works quite nicely. Thank you for that!

Comment: When I will have time I'll try to elaborate on how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't understand why `'op` must outlive `'static`. The lifetime of the returned `Task` is bound by `'b` which in turn is shorter than the `Self` of the boxed closure, and thus of `'op`.

Who said? The only thing the compiler knows about it is that it is required to be true for *any* lifetime (HRTB). *Any* lifetime includes `'static`, and therefore the compiler requires `'op: 'b` which implies `'op: 'static`.

Comment: Ok, that was I wanted to express, but apparently failed to do so. The workaround that you posted in a comment on the question works quite nicely, though!